# Creating a React app with 'create-react-app my-app' for the first time not working

Tags: reactjs

After typing npx create-react-app my-app on Git bash terminal I got

1.prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Also I typed npx create-react-app my-app on my CMD I got
2." prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please how can I fix this

Comment: Do you have `node` and `npx` installed and set in your `PATH` environment variable? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: Yes I have everything installed, I even installed the latest version of node but it's not working